# Google Maps API GeoCoder not returning coordinates

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-geocoder

In trying to apply a published example to my code, I got the following reference error message for 'results': ReferenceError: results is not defined

This is the code where I encountered the error the the line where geocoder.geocode is called:

```
            function GamesCloseBy() {

            var myResult;
            var addressText = $('#<%= UserAddress.ClientID %>').val();
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressText }, async function (results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    alert("coordinates = " + await results[0].geometry.location);
                    myResult = await results[0].geometry.location;
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
            :
            :
       }
```

I have a value of "" for status, and a valid address text for addressText. Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Thank You

ADDED NOTES:

It appears that my callback function, function(results, status), is not actually being called. What do I need to do in order for the function to be called?

My console keeps issuing: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined However, in my .aspx file:  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&libraries=geometry"></script>`

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing brace to me. Count them and look at which opening brace each one is matched to.

Comment: Good eye, however, I had it correct in the coded version, so it's still with an error. My bad on the copy and paste.

Comment: I am now getting inside the function. The asynch is placed before the callback function, and await is placed before the return value that I want. It appears in the alert while testing, but it does not populate the myResults variable in the next line. I am at a loss for understanding this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think there is no need to define a callback function as async, define it as ordinary callback function.